# Left column as wide as it needs to be

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to write a webpage with a simple two column layout, left column is the table of contents and suchlike, right column is the actual content. All the examples I've seen so far hardwire the left column width in pixels, which obviously isn't ideal. What's the recommended way in CSS to say "make the left column as wide as it needs to be, right column takes the rest of the available space"?

Answer (score 2):

Just don't specify a fixed `width`. If you want to control the minimum or maximum width then use `min-width` and `max-width` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
.left_col{min-width: 10px;} 
.right_col{max-width: 20px;}
```

Comment: That's still hardwiring in pixels, though, which is a great way to create something that looks okay on my machine, and looks terrible on somebody else's machine where the fonts or screen resolution or something else I haven't thought of is different.

Comment: Yes, i just given for example only, we could use % instead of PX

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the width of the left column using a percentage and the same goes for the right column. for example:

```
left_column { width: 30% }
right_column: { width: 70%}
```

Comment: And if the content of the left column is over 30% of the parent?  The OP wants a flexible left column so that if the content only takes up 15%, the column is only 15% wide. Not a fluid-layout where you still have a "fixed" width (albeit relative to the browser window)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the navigation to float left. The sizing will happen automatically.

The HTML:

```
<div class="nav">Navigation</div>
<div class="content">Body Text</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.nav {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: just make sure you clear the float, after all your floats, otherwise your layout will suffer more issues.

Comment: But that makes the body text flow back to the full width of the screen as soon as it's past the bottom of the navigation text. How do you make the body text stay within its original width, as though the navigation column were infinitely long?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this without specifying some type of width as the other answers have done.

Comment: Hmm. One option would be to use a table, but on the face of it that would involve losing the @media feature of CSS where you can dynamically switch to a one column layout on a narrow display e.g. cell phone. Is there any way to have both?

Answer (score 0):

Make this your HTML

```
<div class="left">Left Div</div>
<div class="right">Right Div</div>
```

And your CSS

```
.left {float:left; width:auto;}
.right {float:right; width:auto;}
```

You could add margins and or padding to make a little space between the two.

This should be all that is needed for a fluid layout.

EDIT: If one appears below the other add

```
display:inline-block;
```

to each the left and the right class.

Comment: Even when I add the inline-block, the right division appears below the left division.

Comment: It seems that the width of both columns and their padding and margins add hp to over 100% of the page width. do you have your code to show?